# Will using PLCrashReporter disable iTunes connect crash reporting?

Tags: crash, itunes, app-store-connect, plcrashreporter

I am using PLCrashRepoter in my App. In iTunes Connect I don't see any crash reports, but my app is downloaded 50000+ times, so its quite likely that crashs / reports would occur. Yet iTunes Connect does not show any reports.

After very simple handling I call `[crashReporter purgePendingCrashReport];` on App start.
So I was wondering - am I by that deleting the crashReports that elsewise iTunes would upload to iTunes connect?

I have looked into the code, and it seems that purgePendingCrashReports is only deleting from a dictionary it created itself.

Inside PlCrashReporter I also found:

> NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaught_exception_handler);

Could it be that this is overriding an defaultHandler that the mechanism for iTunes connect upload is depending on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PLCrashReporter does **NOT** disable Apples crash reporting functionality. The reason you don't see crash reports in iTunes Connect is because of the way it collects and aggregates crash reports.

1. Crash Reports are only send if the user did agree to send anonymous usage data of the device to Apple. This is very general and most users simply say no.
2. Since iOS 5 crash reports are send directly from the device, in (unknown) intervals, before they where send once the device was synced with iTunes (which is rarely done).
3. Crash Reports only appear until each type of crash passes an (unknown) amount of crash reports.
4. You can only refresh the crash data for your app version once per day.

Usually it takes at least 2 weeks until you see something showing up in iTunes Connect, lots of times it takes much longer or even nothing shows up ever.

Comment: Thats for the answer! Point 3. I didn't know. Could you please get more into detail why PLCrashRepoter does not interfere with Apples Crash reporting? Why are you certain about it?

Comment: Because I am using it since nearly 4 years, I contributed to it, I wrote an open source framework on top of it called QuincyKit, I am co-founder of HockeyApp.net, which is a web service providing crash reporting infrastructure, the developer of it is one of the best developers I know and you can easily test it: Install it and let your app crash without Xcode connected. Then open the organizer and check the device logs section. In addition Apple's crash reporting is an external process and PLCrashReporter runs within your app.

Comment: In addition here are two blog posts of other developers explaining this: http://taptaptap.com/blog/cameraplus-2-3-1-available-attack-of-the-crashinator/ and http://www.futuretap.com/blog/where-to-3-0-5-and-the-truth-about-itunes-connect-crash-reports/